# Converting KML to JSON or shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, convert, kml, json

[image: table of attribute]

I have a KML file open in QGIS and I want to convert it to JSON or shapefile, but many attributes are merged in one as you see in the picture in the description field as HTML code, how to extract these attributes from this HTML code?

Comment: You need an ETL that can flatten the xml format then you can extract the data into more useable attributes.

Comment: Can you make the kml file available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add your KML as a layer to QGIS

[image]

- Export to GeoJSON or GeoPackage

[image]

- Go to [planemad/qgis-extract-html-attributes](https://github.com/planemad/qgis-extract-html-attributes) and save the [`extract_html_attributes.py`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/planemad/qgis-extract-html-attributes/master/extract_html_attributes.py) script.

  - Note the requirement to install the  `BeautifulSoup4` python package.
- Open the Plugins -> Python Console
- Click Show Editor and open the `extract_html_attributes.py` script you saved previously in the editor
- Select the GeoJSON layer in the table of contents
- Run the script

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this on but it gives me invalid syntax

Comment: Save the [`extract_html_attributes.py` script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/planemad/qgis-extract-html-attributes/master/extract_html_attributes.py) and open it rather than copy/paste maybe? It works fine for me.

Comment: it works for me bro, thanks a lot for your support

Comment: I get some KeyErrors from some of the KMLs, Did you come across this problem?

Comment: No, but ask a new Q. with the exact error text (inc. line number) and a KML that causes it.