# KMZ to shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, google-earth, kmz

I want to convert a KMZ to shapefile without losing the attribute table data in the KMZ but when I import the KMZ it creates a different table with none of the data I need.

The new table just has columns like timestamp, drawOrder, icon, etc...

How can I import this KMZ and still have the data records attached to each object?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of the KML text containing the attributes

Comment: I'm removing the _arcgis_ products from your question. You have a QGIS answer. Best to keep questions to one product.

Comment: Depends on the structure of your KML. Are you able to share a copy or a sample?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "KML Tools" plugin, it has the option "expand HTML Description Field", with it you can recover existing fields in KMZ/KML, for example, those that appear in Google Earth, but not in QGIS.

[image: Finding the plugin]

[image: Selecting Layer and Field to expand]

Comment: This might be the right answer but we don't know what the OPs KML looks like.  If it's   GeoServer generated KML with `attr-name` & `attr-value` html, then the KML Tools plugin doesn't support this and [another method is required](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/446607/2856)